# Jump to the end of data in all sheets, not just the current one

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 10 sheets. All of them with ~1000 rows.

I need to go to the end on every tab, not just first sheet.

How can I do that?

Imagine 100 sheets (tabs) in one spreadsheet. All 1000 lines or more. Every time I go to new sheet(tab) I have to scroll down to the end of it. What can be done to avoid scrolling and getting me to either last edited place (in every sheet) or end of data range.
I'm using Windows 10 or Windows 8, US standard keyboard.

Comment: If a keyboard shortcut could work for you, please add the OS and Keyboard layout that you use.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something like that:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{name:"goto_last", functionName:"goto_last"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
   myFunction();
};

function goto_last() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var lastrow = mysheet.getLastRow();

  mysheet.setActiveCell(mysheet.getDataRange().offset(lastrow-1, 0, 1, 1));
};
```

thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

There is not built-in one step way to go to the last edited cell or the last cell of data range.

## Explanation

- Google Sheets resets the active cell position on each sheet every time that the spreadsheet is opened (including if the browser tab is refreshed).
- Google Apps Script doesn't include an event "on tab activation" or similar, so it's not possible to automatically jump to the last cell when the user goes from one tab to another. There is an on open event that could be used to do this but this will require to save the spreadsheet tab URL, use it to open each tab instead of the web UI and is slower than using the proposed keyboard shortcut.

### Workaround

Let say that an sheet area is delimited by empty rows and columns and that the row/columns borders are the first and last row/columns with data.

To navigate between area borders until you reach the last cell of the data range on a device with Windows 8/10 with US standard keyboard

1. Open the tab
2. If you are not at the last edited cell or last cell of the data range, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to jump to the next row border the "current area" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to the next column border of the "current area".
3. Repeat 2 as necessary.

Comment: Ctrl+ End takes mes to the end of spreadsheet. My tab has 1000 rows but information goes only till row 500 for example. So it doesn't help.

Comment: On a comment you said "...to the end of it". Please edit your question to make it clear that you want the end of the data range instead the end of the sheet.

Comment: @Needhelp: Thanks for updating your question. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Official reference for keyboard shortcuts: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en